# Multiple paths for the same handler in fastify

Tags: fastify

In fastify, is there a way I can add an alias to a route/ path? Basically, having two paths be handled the same way. This is useful for migrating an APIs.

I understand that I can abstract the handler function into a named function, and pass that function to both routes. I am just wondering if there's another way to do so?

Comment: It appears that there was a relevant feature request a few years ago, which was decided not to be implemented as commented here https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/151#issuecomment-418102346

Answer (score 8):

No, there is not the feature to set an array of routes to one handler ([here the registration logic if you would like to add this feature](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/a9700280630dc8769612b5625c3a38da4dc9a161/lib/route.js#L99)).

I would suggest registering routes like this:

```js
['/', '/alias'].forEach(path => {
  fastify.route({
    method: ['GET'], // you could define multiple methods
    url: path,
    handler: mySharedHandler
  })
})
```